# Как в signalR сделать правильно access denied?

Tags: android, c#

Используем свой механизм авторизации в signalR по полям token и id
Тех кто не прошел авторизацию, надо отрубить и "послать", например, по 401.
Как это реализовать?
И как это отловить на клиенте, что именно не прошла авторизация?

Answer (score 1):

Это должно быть так. На стороне сервера -- средствами MVC, т.е. нужно писать свой фильтр и применять для хабов или глобально (см. `Authorize` и [здесь например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971401/asp-net-mvc-custom-authorization)). Там же можно и выбрасывать 401 или что-то другое. На стороне клиента вообще отлавливаете ошибки через `$.connection.hub.error(handleErrors);`. Но были ошибки: иногда не вызывался обработчик (может пофиксили уже?) и приходилось: `this._signalrAdapter.operatorHub.server.someServerMethod().fail(handleErrors);`
Удачи!

(Ну и полезно [это](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security) почитать будет, думаю.)